# mySQL COUNT patterns?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

So I've normalized my data. And now I want to obtain some higher level stats about an entity in the DB. So I have to use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`.

Here is what I have, it seems verbose though:

```
SELECT (name, areas, description,) FROM group g WHERE g.id = ?;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group_projects gp WHERE gp.groupID = ?; 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group_users gu WHERE gu.groupID = ?; 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group_followers gf WHERE gf.groupID = ?;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group_members gm WHERE gm.groupID = ?;
```

Then I would have my statistics. Seems like there should be a pattern for this kind of thing, much neater than what I have. Anyone?

Comment: Not really.  You can use `union all`, `cross join`, or scalar subqueries to put these all in one result set.  However, you have a bunch of different tables, so there is no "pattern" method for combining them.

Comment: Ok. How would a `union all` or `cross join` look? I assume just a `UNION` inbetween each statement...

Comment: . . The same queries, just connected with a `cross join`, for instance.